# Embedding of finite groups in Symmetric Groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, and $n$ is the least positive integer such that $G$ can be embedded in symmetric group $S_n$, then, should $G$ necessarily contain a subgroup of index $n$?

Comment: There is a cyclic group of order 6 in $S_5$.

Comment: Is it actually known how to compute the least $n$ such that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n?$

Comment: @Igor: I think, its not completely known (this problem (your) was posed on mathoverflow).  In group theory, if we want to show that a group is isomorphic to $A_n$ or $S_n$, it follows easily if we have subgroup of index $n$. But "Is it correct step to show existence of index n subgroup?", this was a question I wondering.  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. The group $S_3 \times S_2$ can be embedded in $S_5$, but not in smaller symmetric groups.